# Firebird 2.5 C++ client: error with DATE data type

Tags: database-connection, firebird

Environment: **Firebird 2.5.4-64bit, on Windows 8.1.**

I'm trying to write a C++ client using the C client API (using VS2013). I receive this error when preparing a SELECT statement on a table containing a DATE column (error when calling isc_dsql_prepare function)

> Dynamic SQL Error
>   -SQL error code = -804
>   -Data type unknown
>   -Client SQL dialect 1 does not support reference to DATE datatype

From isql tool, I confirm the database is using SQL dialect 3:
SQL> show sql dialect;
        Client SQL dialect is set to: 3 and database SQL dialect is: 3

On the client side, I am setting the SQL dialect to be 3 (at least I dont have error on attaching):

```
uint32_t sqlDialect = 3;
    const char* charset = "UTF8";
    char dpbBuffer[256], *dpb, *p;

    dpb = dpbBuffer;
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_version1;
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_user_name;
    *dpb++ = user.size();
    strcpy(dpb, user.c_str());
    dpb += user.size();
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_password;
    *dpb++ = pwd.size();
    strcpy(dpb, pwd.c_str());
    dpb += pwd.size();
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_lc_ctype;
    *dpb++ = 4;
    strcpy(dpb, charset);
    dpb += 4;
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_sql_dialect;
    memcpy(dpb, &sqlDialect, 4);
    dpb += 4;

    short dpbLength = dpb - dpbBuffer;

    if (isc_attach_database(status, 0, url.c_str(), &_db, dpbLength, dpbBuffer))
    {
        isc_print_status(status);
    }
```

I have no issue with TIMESTAMP columns, hence I could set all my DATE columns to be of type TIMESTAMP, but I wish someone could explain the error message.

**SOLUTION:**
Many thanks to Mark Rotteveel who pointed out the exact issue.

First, more information on how I prepare the statement:

```
std::string sql = "SELECT * FROM truc";
out_sqlda = (XSQLDA *)malloc(XSQLDA_LENGTH(NbColumn));
out_sqlda->version = SQLDA_VERSION1;
out_sqlda->sqln = NbColumn;
isc_stmt_handle stmt;
isc_dsql_allocate_statement(status, &_db, &stmt);
isc_dsql_prepare(status, &(TransactHandle), &stmt, 0, sql.c_str(), 1, out_sqlda);
```

I got abused by the Interbase API guide pdf which gives the following:

```
isc_dsql_prepare(
status_vector,
&trans, /* Set by previous isc_start_transaction() call. */
&stmt, /* Statement handle set by this function call. */
0, /* Specifies statement string is null-terminated. */
str, /* Statement string. */
SQLDA_VERSION1, /* XSQLDA version number. */
out_sqlda /* XSQLDA for storing column data. */
);
```

But the 6th parameter is NOT the SQLDA version, but the SQL dialect!!! Putting 3 solves the issue.
Looking at the code of the .Net provider was very helpful as well.

Comment: Show the code you use to prepare and execute the query; there are some methods that also take a dialect parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously commented, some methods in the API take the SQL dialect version as the parameter (`isc_dsql_prepare`, `isc_dsql_execute_immediate` and `isc_dsql_exec_immed2`). If you call these with the parameter `1` instead of `3` your statement will be parsed as a dialect 1 statement.

As you note an example in the Interbase 6 API Guide (on page 122) says it is the SQLDA version. My guess is that in a previous version of Interbase (dialects were introduced in version 6) this parameter **was** the SQLDA version (see for example `isc_describe` which takes a `da_version` parameter before the `XSQLDA` parameter), and that they reused this parameter to keep the method parameter types and counts the same. The fact that some of these methods need the `da_version` parameter at all is kind of weird (the sqlda version is part of the `XSQLDA`).